# Prevent cell numbers from incrementing in a formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a formula in Excel that needs to be run on several rows of a column based on the numbers in that row divided by one constant. When I copy that formula and apply it to every cell in the range, all of the cell numbers increment with the row, including the constant. So:

```
B1=127
C4='=IF(B4<>"",B4/B1,"")'
```

If I copy cell C4 and paste it down column C, the formula becomes

```
=IF(B5<>"",B5/B2,"")
=IF(B6<>"",B6/B3,"")
etc.
```

when what I need it to be is

```
=IF(B5<>"",B5/B1,"")
=IF(B6<>"",B6/B1,"")
etc.
```

Is there a simple way to prevent the expression from incrementing?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

There is something called 'locked reference' in excel which you can use for this, and you use `$` symbols to lock a range. For your example, you would use:

```
=IF(B4<>"",B4/B$1,"")
```

This locks the `1` in `B1` so that when you copy it to rows below, `1` will remain the same.

If you use `$B$1`, the range will not change when you copy it down a row or across a column.

Answer (score 24):

In Excel 2013 and resent versions, you can use <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> to speed things up when you want to toggle the lock.

About the keys:

- <kbd>F2</kbd> - With a cell selected, it places the cell in formula edit mode.
- <kbd>F4</kbd>  - Toggles the cell reference lock (the $ signs).
- Example scenario with 'A4'.

  - Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> will convert 'A4' into '$A$4'
  - Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> again converts '$A$4' into 'A$4'
  - Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> again converts 'A$4' into '$A4'
  - Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> again converts '$A4' back to the original 'A4'

How To:

- In Excel, select a cell with a formula and hit <kbd>F2</kbd>  to enter formula
  edit mode. You can also perform these next steps directly in the
  Formula bar. (Issue with <kbd>F2</kbd> ? Double check that 'F Lock' is on)

  - If the formula has one cell reference;

    - Hit <kbd>F4</kbd>  as needed and the single cell reference will toggle.
  - If the forumla has more than one cell reference, hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>  (without highlighting anything) will toggle the last cell reference in the formula.
  - If the formula has more than one cell reference and you want to change them all;

    - You can use your mouse to highlight the entire formula or you can use the following keyboard shortcuts;
    - Hit <kbd>End</kbd> key (If needed. Cursor is at end by default)
    - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> keys to highlight the entire formula
    - Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> as needed
  - If the formula has more than one cell reference and you only want to edit specific ones;

    - Highlight the specific values with your mouse or keyboard ( <kbd>Shift</kbd> and arrow keys) and then hit <kbd>F4</kbd> as needed.

Notes:

- These notes are based on my observations while I was looking into this for one of my own projects.
- It only works on one cell formula at a time.
- Hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>  without selecting anything will update the locking on the last cell reference in the formula.
- Hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>  when you have mixed locking in the formula will convert everything to the same thing. Example two different cell references like '$A4' and 'A$4' will both become 'A4'. This is nice because it can prevent a lot of second guessing and cleanup.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does not work in the formula editor but you can hit the End key and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> to highlight the entire formula. Hitting
  <kbd>Home</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>.
- OS and Hardware manufactures have many different keyboard bindings for the Function (F Lock) keys so <kbd>F2</kbd>  and <kbd>F4</kbd> may do different things. As an example, some users may have to hold down you 'F Lock' key on some laptops.
- 'DrStrangepork' commented about <kbd>F4</kbd> actually closes Excel which can be true but it depends on what you last selected. Excel changes the behavior of <kbd>F4</kbd> depending
  on the current state of Excel. If you have the cell selected and are
  in formula edit mode (<kbd>F2</kbd>), <kbd>F4</kbd> will toggle cell reference locking as Alexandre had originally suggested. While playing with this, I've had <kbd>F4</kbd> do at least 5 different things. I view <kbd>F4</kbd> in Excel as an all purpose function key that behaves something like this; "*As an Excel user, given my last action, automate or repeat logical next step for me*".

Answer (score 13):

**TL:DR**
row lock = `A$5`
column lock = `$A5`
Both = `$A$5`

**Below are examples of how to use the Excel lock reference `$` when creating your formulas**

To prevent increments when moving from one row to another put the $ after the column letter and before the row number. e.g. `A$5`

To prevent increments when moving from one column to another put the $ before the row number. e.g. `$A5`

To prevent increments when moving from one column to another or from one row to another put the $ before the row number and before the column letter. e.g. `$A$5`

Using the lock reference will prevent increments when dragging cells over to duplicate calculations.

Answer (score 7):

Highlight "B1" and press F4. This will lock the cell.

Now you can drag it around and it will not change. The principle is simple. It adds a dollar sign before both coordinates. A dollar sign in front of a coordinate will lock it when you copy the formula around. You can have partially locked coordinates and fully locked coordinates.

Comment: Selecting "B1" and hitting F4 closes Excel.

Comment: No it does not. Is it a Mac or some sort of exotic version of Excel ? Did you do Alt+F4 instead of just F4 ? There is no way F4 alone closes Excel.

Comment: Excel 2013 (office 365). I tried it on two different sheets with multiple cells. As far as I can tell, it functions just like Alt-F4 - offer to save and then quit. I thought maybe this was because I still had the VBA window open, but closing that first did not change the result. It is still happening today after a reboot.
With a different spreadsheet, F4 did nothing. The contents were copied to other cells just as in my original post.