# All variables in an IF statement increment instead of just one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a problem not unlike the problem here [Prevent cell numbers from incrementing in a formula in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181264/prevent-cell-numbers-from-incrementing-in-a-formula-in-excel) except I am using SUMIF($A:$A,"3/13/2014",$F:$F). I would like to get the date to increment which is was doing up until I locked the other variables not excel won't increment the middle variable.

a little more info:  column A is a series of dates and column F is a total of tons moved that day. There are no other formulas on the page to conflict with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand your question correctly, you're looking to increment the date part of your formula... There are MANY ways to do this, but the way that come to mind for me right now would be something along these lines:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,"3/13/2014"+ROW(A1)-1,$F:$F)
```

What this will do is, as you drag it down, it will increment the `ROW(A1)` part to the next row and hence add an extra day to the date.

Hope this does the trick...